# Isotope Filtering by Post Tags on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, tags, filtering

I've already done the isotope filtering to filter posts by categories. But I also need to filter posts by tags on the same page. I’m still new to wordpress so I really hope someone can give me any advice on how to do this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you need to echoe the tags in the class, so that isotope can identify the filters.

See below from the isotope site:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item transition metal">...</div>
  <div class="item post-transition metal">...</div>
  <div class="item alkali metal">...</div>
  <div class="item transition metal">...</div>
  <div class="item lanthanoid metal inner-transition">...</div> 
  <div class="item halogen nonmetal">...</div> 
  <div class="item alkaline-earth metal">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

[Source](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html)

Then you need to echoe the tag list and adjust your code to filter on click.

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
  <button data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
  <button data-filter=".transition">transition</button>
  <button data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali & alkaline-earth</button>
  <button data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</button>
  <button data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</button>
</div>
```

Have a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags).

In theory it should work the same as categories.

See